# Why can’t we override a base class method with private extended class method?

Tags: java, methods, overriding

```
class One {
    void foo() { }
}
class Two extends One {
    private void foo() { /* more code here */ }
}
```

Why is the above snippet of code wrong?

Comment: you cannot reduce visibility of a method in java, you can increase it, order of visibility (lowest->highest): private, package private (i.e. no modifier), protected, public.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*I'm going to try to incorporate the ideas from the other answers to come up with a single answer.*

First off, let's take a look at what's going on in the code.

**A look at the code**

The `One` class has a package-private `foo` method:

```
class One {
    // The lack of an access modifier means the method is package-private.
    void foo() { }
}
```

The `Two` class which subclasses the `One` class, and the `foo` method is overriden, but has the access modifier `private`.

```
class Two extends One {
    // The "private" modifier is added in this class.
    private void foo() { /* more code here */ }
}
```

**The issue**

The Java language does not allow subclasses to reduce the visibility of a method, field or class in a subclass, therefore, the `Two` class reducing the visibility of the `foo` method is not legal.

*Why is reducing visibility a problem?*

Consider the case where we want to use the `One` class:

```
class AnotherClass {
  public void someMethod() {
     One obj = new One();
     obj.foo();  // This is perfectly valid.
  }
}
```

Here, calling the `foo` method on the `One` instance is valid. (Assuming that the `AnotherClass` class is in the same package as the `One` class.)

Now, what if we were to instantiate the `Two` object and place it in the `obj` variable of the type `One`?

```
class AnotherClass {
  public void someMethod() {
     One obj = new Two();
     obj.foo();  // Wait a second, here...
  }
}
```

The `Two.foo` method is private, yet, the `One.foo` method would allow the access to the method. We've got a problem here.

Therefore, it doesn't make much sense to allow reduction of visibility when taking inheritance into account.

**Links**

- [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) - Explanations of access modifiers from The Java Tutorials.

Comment: +1 As someone who wrote one of the other answers, this is a great summary that's very well-written.  Thanks for putting this together!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this code is that if it were legal, Java wouldn't be able to respect the `private` modifier of `foo` if you accessed it indirectly through the `One` base class.  For example, if I were to write

```
One obj = new Two();
obj.foo();
```

Then we'd be in trouble because we'd be calling the `private` method `foo` of `Two` indirectly, since when the compiler checks the line `obj.foo()` it looks at `One` to determine if `foo` is accessible, not at `Two`.  The reason for this is that the compiler can't always tell what `obj` could be pointing at - if, for example, I write something like

```
One obj = Math.random() < 0.5? new One() : new Two();
obj.foo();
```

Then the compiler can't know whether `obj` points at a `One` or a `Two`.  Consequently, it defers to `One` when checking access specifiers.  If we were indeed allowed to mark `foo` private in `Two`, then the compiler would incorrectly allow us to call it through `obj`, which has type `One`, bypassing the guarantee that only the object itself can call `private` methods.

Comment: the real issue is that reducing visibility is not allowed in java. even if the 1st method was protected and the 2nd package private, the compiler would have been able to compile, but the declaration ain't allowed.

Comment: @bestsss- Yes, that's true, but the reasoning behind this decision is an extension of the above logic.

Answer (score 1):

The given answers give you the technical explanation why you cannot extend One by Two. I would like to give you an understanding why this is not possible due to the object oriented pattern and not because of the language itself.

Usually the class One is a general definition of a class with its accessors, the methods, to the outer world. Sublcasses which extend this class must provide the same accessors to the outer world. Two extends One in your example, what means, that Two provides the same accessors to the outer world like One does. If you would change the visibility of the accessors of One, the outer world could no longer access your class as they are used to do it with an object of type One.

Answer (score 0):

It would break polymorphism.

If you have a Two instance stored in a Two variable, then it would make sense that foo cannot be called. But if you store a Two instance in a One variable, you only know about One. But One's have a public foo, and that can be called. This would be an inconsistency and would be really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Because inheritance is a *is a* relationship. Anyone could refer to a instance of `Two` through a reference to `One` :

```
One v = new Two();
```

What would the program do if you called the foo method on the v reference? You broke the public contract of One, which guarantees that every instance of One has a (here package-protected) foo method. That's why the compiler forbids it.