# What about public method returns private class instance?

Tags: java, class, package, private, public

I am trying to test the following situation:

1. There is a main. (`city.Main`)
2. There is a package. (`package castle`)
3. Within the package, there is a public class (`castle.Guard`), and a *package-private* class (`castle.Princess`).
4. **What if, the public class is returning an instance of the private class?**

Here is my code:

**Main.java**

```
package city;

import castle.Guard;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Princess princess = Guard.getPrincessStatic();
        // Error: Princess cannot be resolved to a type
        
        Guard.getPrincessStatic().sayHi();
        // Error: The type Princess is not visible
        
        Guard guard = new Guard();
        guard.getPrincess().sayHi();
        // Error: The type Princess is not visible
        
        guard.getPrincessMember().sayHi();
        // Error: The type Princess is not visible
    }

}
```

**Guard.java**

```
package castle;

public class Guard {

    public Princess getPrincess() {
        return new Princess();
    }

    public static Princess getPrincessStatic() {
        return new Princess();
    }
    
    private Princess m_princess = new Princess();
    
    public Princess getPrincessMember() {
        return m_princess;
    }
}
```

**Princess.java**

```
package castle;

class Princess {
    public void sayHi() { System.out.println("Hi world"); }
}
```

*Notice all the 4 statements in `main()` are having errors.*

I have done some research too. In fact i want to mimic [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5414217/1884546). But i don't why my codes throw errors.

Thanks for any explanations!

---

## Edit:

I intend to make the `castle-Princess` *package-private*. I know that, by returning a *package-private* class out of its package, I should be prepared for errors. But why [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5414217/1884546) works, while mine doesn't?

Comment: The errors are basically saying "private means *private*!"  These links might help: [Java Language Spec: visibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#d5e8032), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203205/why-cant-we-override-a-base-class-method-with-private-extended-class-method, [Visibility and Coupling](http://www.leepoint.net/JavaBasics/oop/oop-70-visibility.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Princess` class is default scoped to `castle` package , so its invisible within `city` package . To circumvent that :

*(We can do one of the following three approaches.)*

## 1) Make `Princess` class `public` and use it .

```
package castle;

// added public modifier
public class Princess {
     public void sayHi() { System.out.println("Hi world"); }
}
```

## 2) Or, Define a `public interface` and let `Princess` implement it and use the `interface reference` instead of the `class reference` . I would prefer this .

**castle \ IPrincess.java**

```
// Interface definition
package castle;

public interface IPrincess {
    public void sayHi();
}
```

**castle \ Princess.java**

```
// Implement the interface in Princess class
package castle;

class Princess implements IPrincess {
    public void sayHi() { System.out.println("Hi world"); }
}
```

**castle \ Guard.java**

```
// Modify the Guard class
package castle;

public class Guard {
    public IPrincess getPrincess() {
        return new Princess();
    }
    public static IPrincess getPrincessStatic() {
        return new Princess();
    }

    // for here i use Princess instead of IPrincess. (@midnite)
    private Princess m_princess = new Princess();
    public IPrincess getPrincessMember() {
        return m_princess;
    }
}
```

**city \ Main.java**

```
// Modify the main class
  package city;

  import castle.Guard;
  import castle.IPrincess;

  public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     IPrincess princess = Guard.getPrincessStatic();

     Guard.getPrincessStatic().sayHi();

     Guard guard = new Guard();
     guard.getPrincess().sayHi();

     guard.getPrincessMember().sayHi();
   }
}
```

## 3) Or, Put all the classes in same package .

Comment: This is really a nice solution!! Please allow me to edit a little bit of your answer for better readability :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to return a type that is privately scoped within a class. How can any external sources know what that type even IS if it's privately scope inside of another class?

This design won't even compile.

**Edit:**

The simple solution is to make it public and then you can use it externally outside of the package.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer you are trying to mimic works because all the classes are inside the same package**.

If you put `UntrustworthyFriend` and `Friend` in different packages (as your scenario), the same problems will arise.

`Princess` can only be visible outsite it's package if `public`:

**Princess.java**

```
package castle;

public class Princess {
    public void sayHi() { System.out.println("Hi world"); }
}
```

Also, make sure to import it in `Main`.

Comment: You are right! If i put `UntrustworthyFriend.java` and `Friend.java` in different packages, the line `friendWithSecret.getMySecret().reveal()` gives Error: `The type Secret is not visible`. So, in my point of view, what @Andy want to illustrate is just returning a private member variable, instead of a private class, that is not really special IMO (all our getter methods do so).

Comment: @midnite: @Andy says _"However, methods can still be invoked on `Secret` from within `UntrustworthyFriend`."_ Still, this only holds true if `Secret` is visible from `UntrustworthyFriend`. And it will only be so if `Secret` is either `public` or in the same package as `UntrustworthyFriend`.

Comment: @ acdc junior: Yup. In `UntrustworthyFriend.main()`, i can even do `System.out.println( (new Secret("blah")).reveal() );`. i don't really need a `Friend` at all :-/

Comment: Indeed. Who needs a friend when you got stackoverflow? :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in a very small error in the definition of your Princess class:

```
package castle;

class Princess {
    public void sayHi() { System.out.println("Hi world"); }
}
```

All looks fine at first, but you're missing a `public` modifier before the class name:

```
package castle;

//here!
public class Princess {
    public void sayHi() { System.out.println("Hi world"); }
}
```

Without the public modifier, the princess class cannot be accessed outside of the file in which it is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is different because your classes are in different packages and Guard and Princess are not visible from Main.

But public method can return an instance of a private class. JDK is full of examples, here is one from `java.util.Arrays`

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
...
private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>  {
...
```

it is what you ask. The trick is that the method's return type is a public interface which the private class implements. You could do something similar.

Comment: Thanks @ED. This is interesting! i guess this should be the trick implemented by @ noob earlier?