# Inheritance-Why can't I declare a private method in a subclass with same method signature in super?

Tags: java, inheritance

My book doesn't give the greatest explanation, and I want to understand why I can't have a private method in the subclass when I have the same method signature in the superclass. Except the method in the superclass would be public.

I tried googling this answer and all I could find was stuff on overriding private methods. However, I'm trying to override a public method with a private method.

Comment: Answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203205/why-cant-we-override-a-base-class-method-with-private-extended-class-method

Comment: Thanks you! ^^^ 
Both Nate and BacMan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3), section 8.4.8.3, one cannot weaken the access privilege of a method when overriding, specifically:

> The access modifier (§6.6) of an overriding or hiding method must
>   provide at least as much access as the overridden or hidden method, as
>   follows:
>
> If the overridden or hidden method is public, then the overriding or
>   hiding method must be public; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> If the overridden or hidden method is protected, then the overriding
>   or hiding method must be protected or public; otherwise, a
>   compile-time error occurs.
>
> If the overridden or hidden method has default (package) access, then
>   the overriding or hiding method must not be private; otherwise, a
>   compile-time error occurs.

This is done so if you have a superclass reference to the subclass object, then you can still call that method, no matter what class it is -- the superclass, or any subclass -- e.g.

```
Superclass obj = new Subclass();
obj.method();
```

It must still be `public`.

Answer (score 2):

By making the derived method `private` you'd be changing the contract made by the super class, preventing any further subclasses from accessing the originally `public` method.

A function passed a parameter typed to be of the super class would not know in advance whether it's allowed to call the method or not.  This would be bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you could, then what? You'd have overridden a public method with a private one, that would make the super class method invisible. Code counting on having that method available would break. One of the ideas of OO (called the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56904/217324)) is that the program should be able to manipulate objects at a high level, without having to know the exact implementation class being used; objects of any subclass should be substitutable for objects of their superclass. Being able to invalidate super class methods would undermine this.